# How to execute a cleanup command on tmux server/session exit?

Tags: command-line, tmux, session-restore, session-manager

To improve my workflow a little I have written a few wrapper scripts to automatically start some commands when I want to work on a project. When I'm done however, and clean all the tmux tabs for this specific session I would like to kill some processes and cleanup some files.

Is there any way to automatically execute a command when exiting the tmux server?

The wanted workflow:

- execute command to create new tmux server, open some files, start a few apps
- work in the session
- detach to work on it later
- reattach
- when all tabs in the tmux server are closed and the server is destroyed, execute a cleanup command

[edit]The script I currently use: https://github.com/WoLpH/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/tmx

Comment: by "cleanup command" you mean a server-specific command? For example, you have a session open for project A and another session for project B. So you want to execute cleanup_A when session_A is closed? Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. But a general cleanup command can work too, I can easily deduce the previously opened project from the remaining files. I just need any kind of post-server-exit trigger so I can unmount some things.

Comment: I've written a command-line utility for scripting tmux session setup/teardown: https://github.com/tarruda/tmuxer. It even includes a replacement to 'choose-session' that will let you choose 'closed' sessions

Comment: @ThiadodeArruda: that looks cool, I'll test it soon. Currently I am using this script: https://github.com/WoLpH/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/tmx

Comment: @Wolph: I also had my solution integrated into a dotfiles-zsh script, recently I extracted into a reusable set of posix-compatible shell scripts for better portability and easier reuse by others

Comment: btw, if you're using tmuxinator, you can simply add a `post` command in your config file.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck: that would be a nice alternative indeed. For me it's not really suited as I regularly work on (outdated) servers where I have very little software support and tmuxinator has too much deps to install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now, there is no specific way to have tmux automatically run commands triggered by `detach` or closing all windows in the session. However, since you already have a wrapper script (I will call this `tmux_wrapper`) that opens your desired custom-session, you can easily convert this script to automate cleanup. I do something very similar to this myself [here](https://github.com/scicalculator/tmux-tmx/blob/master/bin/tmx), where I wanted to allow nested tmux sessions if I am attaching through ssh.

Since you have a custom experience in mind, you no longer need the `tmux attach ....` or similar commands, so I will assume you always start session for project A by something like `tmux_wrapper A`. In your wrapper you probably have a line similar to `tmux new-session -s A`. Here we can take advantage of the session name `A`. Then, at the end of your wrapper you can have a cleanup switch that only activates if the session is no longer live (i.e. windows/panes are no longer attachable).

A simple example `tmux_wrapper` would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

sess=$1

# test if the session has windows
is_closed(){ 
    n=$(tmux ls 2> /dev/null | grep "^$sess" | wc -l)
    [[ $n -eq 0 ]]
}

# either create it or attach to it
if is_closed ; then
  tmux new -s $sess
else
  tmux attach -t $sess
fi

# the session is now either closed or detatched
if is_closed ; then
    # perform cleanup here ...
fi
```

Run it like `tmux_wrapper A`. Now, the cleanup will automatically occur for session A if and only if the session has been completely closed.

Comment: Not the prettiest solution but it should work :) Thanks! I indeed have a similar script, you can find it here if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/WoLpH/3163775